# Python: how to extract "data-bind" html elements?

Tags: python, html, data-binding, web-scraping, data-extraction

I am trying to extract data from a website. The element is hidden. when i try to "view source", the header text is not displayed.

```
<h4 data-bind="Text: Name"></h4>
```

But when i try to inspect, there is text visible.

```
<h4 data-bind="Text: Name">STM1F-1S-HC</h4>
```

The code used is:

```
def getlink(link):
    try:
        f = urllib.request.urlopen(link)
        soup0 = BeautifulSoup(f)
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
        soup0 = 'abc'
    for row2 in soup0.findAll("h4",{"data-bind":"text: Name"}):
        Name = row2.text
        print(Name)

#code to find all links to the products for further processing.
i=1
global i
for row in r1.findAll('a', { "class" : "col-xs-12 col-sm-6" }):
    link = 'https://www.truemfg.com/USA-Foodservice/'+row['href']
    print(link)
    getlink(link)
print(productcount)
```

The output is:

```
https://www.truemfg.com/USA-Foodservice/Products/Traditional-Reach-Ins
C:\Users\Santosh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py:181: UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("lxml"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

The code that caused this warning is on line 193 of the file C:\Users\Santosh\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py. To get rid of this warning, change code that looks like this:

 BeautifulSoup([your markup])

to this:

 BeautifulSoup([your markup], "lxml")

  markup_type=markup_type))

https://www.truemfg.com/USA-Foodservice/Products/Specification-Series

https://www.truemfg.com/USA-Foodservice/Products/Food-Prep-Tables

https://www.truemfg.com/USA-Foodservice/Products/Undercounters

https://www.truemfg.com/USA-Foodservice/Products/Worktops

https://www.truemfg.com/USA-Foodservice/Products/Chef-Bases

https://www.truemfg.com/USA-Foodservice/Products/Milk-Coolers

https://www.truemfg.com/USA-Foodservice/Products/Glass-Door-Merchandisers

https://www.truemfg.com/USA-Foodservice/Products/Air-Curtains

https://www.truemfg.com/USA-Foodservice/Products/Display-Cases

https://www.truemfg.com/USA-Foodservice/Products/Underbar-Refrigeration
```

we find that there are no names printed.

Could someone let me know a solution to print the names as well.

Thanks,
Santosh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Required content generated dynamically by XHR. You can try below code to request data directly and avoid parsing `HTML`:

```
import requests

url = 'https://prodtrueservices.azurewebsites.net/api/products/productline/403/1?skip=0&take=200&unit=Imperial'
r = requests.get(url)
counter = 0

while True:
    try:
        print(r.json()['Products'][counter]['Name'])
            counter += 1
    except IndexError:
        break
```

This should allow you to get all names

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please let me know how to get the to the url using XHR.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you want to get?

Comment: My requirement is - For all the links in the above output, I would like to extract all product information in an excel sheet and all images and files in a folder and file paths as a column in the sheet. How did you get to the 'https://prodtrueservices.azurewebsites.net/api/products/productline/403/1?skip=0&take=200&unit=Imperial' this url?

Comment: I'm not sure how to get list of Product lines with specific request... It's not the best idea, but you can hardcode the source ID as `pL = [403, 558, 560, 445, 436, 555, 561, 564, 557, 559, 562]` and loop through this list like: `for line in pL: r = requests.get('https://prodtrueservices.azurewebsites.net/api/products/productline/%s/1?skip=0&take=200&unit=Imperial' % line) ... ` Note that you can get link to each image file with `print(r.json()['Products'][0]['ProductImageUrl'])`

Comment: I get https://prodtrueservices.azurewebsites.net/api/products/productline/403/1?skip=0&take=200&unit=Imperial%27 simply from browser dev console

Comment: Ok got it! Thanks!